# Read multiple CSV using numpy loadtxt and for loop not working

Tags: python, numpy, csv, for-loop

I'm trying to output data in multiple CSV files using a for loop using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

# read multiple files

def show_datasets(filenames):
    n = len(filenames)
    data=[]
    for i in range(0, n):
        data = np.loadtxt(filenames[i], delimiter=',', dtype=float)
        return data, i

print(show_datasets(['data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv']))
```

But the it only shows the dataset for the first CSV file and I think the loop ends at i=0 because the return shows the data for data1.csv and then 0 but I don't get why it doesn't go through i = 1, i=2 or show the rest of the CSV file data?

What I'm getting:

```
(array([[ 7.98631, 16.82952, 19.65165],
   [ 7.1446 , 10.41674,  3.81853],
   [ 7.48549, 14.61958,  8.87193],
   [ 8.66521, 14.14244, 10.10248],
   [14.80968, 12.82048, 13.41792]]), 0)
```

What I want:

```
(array([[ 7.98631, 16.82952, 19.65165],
   [ 7.1446 , 10.41674,  3.81853],
   [ 7.48549, 14.61958,  8.87193],
   [ 8.66521, 14.14244, 10.10248],
   [14.80968, 12.82048, 13.41792]]), 0)
(array([[ 12.65900,13.22477,8.94481],
   [ 7.11298,1.99820,8.49168],
   [ 0.25181,9.79979,13.62024],
   [ 8.66521, 14.14244, 10.10248],
   [1.98336,1.42358,9.92036]]), 1)
(array([[ 7.98631, 16.82952, 19.65165],
   [ 14.12714,8.03384,15.76423],
   [ 13.78446,8.92194,15.08250],
   [ 15.79836,6.28136,7.43691],
   [17.93699,0.01700,10.15189]]), 2)
```

Comment: here `return` statement breaks  the `loop` and `funct`. so the next cycle of loop doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `return` statement is inside the `loop`, which causes the function to `exit` and return the data for the first CSV file in the list.

```py
import numpy as np

def show_datasets(filenames):
    n = len(filenames)
    data = []
    for i in range(n):
        data.append(np.loadtxt(filenames[i], delimiter=',', dtype=float))
    return data

# Pass your datasets as required
print(show_datasets(['data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv']))
```

- Created an empty list called data to store the loaded datasets and use `append` method to add each loaded dataset to the data list.
- Move the `return` statement outside the loop to ensure that all datasets are loaded before returning the final result.

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement breaks the `loop` and exit the function.

```
import numpy as np

# read multiple files

def show_datasets(filenames):
    n = len(filenames)
    data=[]
    for i in range(0, n):
        #first element is csv data list, and 2nd element is index
        single_file_data = [np.loadtxt(filenames[i], delimiter=',', dtype=float),i] 
        data.append(single_file_data)
    return data

print(show_datasets(['data1.csv', 'data2.csv', 'data3.csv']))
```

your data is a list containing array at each index. first Element of Array will be the csv file data, and 2nd element will be index.
use append function to add data to `data` list.